# How to use GNU readline with flex-lexer?

Tags: c, readline, flex-lexer, lemon

I think that using the GNU Readline library for a command-line prompt is good and I want that functionality for my shell that I'm working on. Now readline works for me (my environment is CLion, CMake, Ubuntu, BSD, C, flex-lexer and lemon-parser) but I also need flex and yacc to work at the same time to scan and parse the input but the codes seem "incompatible" - are they really?

```
    params[0] = NULL;
   printf("> ");

    i=1;
    do {
        lexCode = yylex(scanner);

        /*  snprintf(shell_prompt, sizeof(shell_prompt), "%s:%s $ ", getenv("USER"), getcwd(NULL, 1024));
         Display prompt and read input (NB: input must be freed after use)...*/



        text = strdup(yyget_text(scanner));
        /*
        input = readline(text);

        if (!input)
            break;

        add_history(input);

        free(input);*/
        printf("lexcode %i Text %s\n", lexCode, text);
        if (lexCode == 4) {
            params[i++] = mystring;
            if (strcmp(text, "\'\0")) {
                params[i++] = mystring;
            }
        } else
        if (lexCode != EOL) {
                params[i++] = text;
                printf("B%s\n", text);
        }
        Parse(shellParser, lexCode, text);
        if (lexCode == EOL) {
            dump_argv("Before exec_arguments", i, params);
            exec_arguments(i, params);
            corpse_collector();
            Parse(shellParser, 0, NULL);
            i=1;
        }
    } while (lexCode > 0);
    if (-1 == lexCode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The scanner encountered an error.\n");
    }
```

The above code has the parsing and scanning working and commented out the readline functionality that won't work if I want both at the same time. Can I make it work?

Comment: An *exemplary* answer would demonstrate *how* to do this, rather than skim over the available resources.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, a posted a quick flex + readline + history example. Suggestions welcome ☺.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read documentation of [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. You'll want to use `readline` only when your *stdin* is a tty, so use [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) as `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` to detect that.

The basic behavior of a shell using `readline`  is simply to use the

```
char *readline (const char *prompt);
```

function. So you want to adapt your parser to read from a buffer, not from `stdin`. This is usual practice. Don't forget to test (against failure) your call to `readline`  and to `free`  the resulting buffer when you are done.

Then, you want to add some [completion](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC45). That is the hard part. Look at what other shells ([`zsh`](http://zsh.org/), [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [`fish`](http://fishshell.com/)...) are doing, at least for inspiration. Notice that the default file-name completion could be enough, at least when starting.

BTW, I won't use both *lemon* and *bison* to parse the same input. Actually, for a shell (since its syntax is quite simple), I'll just use some hand-written [recursive-descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Answer (score 5):

#### flex+readline example

Following a quick flex "shell" that just can `ls` and `date`

```
%{
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <readline/readline.h>
  #include <readline/history.h>
  #define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) result = mygetinput(buf, max_size);

  static int mygetinput(char *buf, int size) {
    char *line;
    if (feof(yyin))  return YY_NULL;
    line = readline("> ");
    if(!line)        return YY_NULL;
    if(strlen(line) > size-2){
       fprintf(stderr,"input line too long\n"); return YY_NULL; }
    sprintf(buf,"%s\n",line);
    add_history(line);
    free(line);
    return strlen(buf);
  }   
%}

%option noyywrap    
%%
ls.*         system(yytext);
date.*       system(yytext);
.+           fprintf(stderr, "Error: unknown comand\n");
[ \t\n]+     {}
%%
```

build it with:

```
flex mysh.fl
cc -o mysh lex.yy.c -lreadline -lfl
```

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?